# How to use sctpsocket_udp class in pysctp library

Tags: python, python-3.7, sctp

I am attempting to set up a basic SCTP client/server example using the pysctp library. I would like to use the `sctp.sctpsocket_udp` class since according to the relevant doc strings:

> A UDP-style SCTP socket can hold several associations via a single socket.

...and this is functionality that I need. Here is what I have so far:

```
server_sock = sctp.sctpsocket_udp(socket.AF_INET)
server_sock.bind((str(ip_address), port))
server_sock.listen(16)
server_sock.settimeout(1)

while not done:
    time.sleep(3)
    fromaddr, flags, msg, notif = server_sock.sctp_recv(3*1024*1024)
```

I have of course omitted things like imports just for the sake of brevity. And the bottom line is that when this is executed I get the following error:

> BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

The corresponding stack trace indicates that the problem is arising on the underlying call to `_sctp.sctp_recv_msg(...)`

Output from strace shows the following:

```
1032 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET|SOCK_CLOEXEC, IPPROTO_SCTP) = 3
1033 getsockopt(3, 0x84 /* SOL_??? */, 2, "\n\0\377\377\10\0`\352", [8]) = 0
1034 getsockopt(3, 0x84 /* SOL_??? */, 11, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", [10]) = 0
1035 bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), in_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
1036 listen(3, 16)                           = 0
1037 ioctl(3, FIONBIO, [1])                  = 0
1038 mmap(NULL, 3149824, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd621646000
1039 recvmsg(3, 0x7ffe1a59ba40, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

I attempted to restart my computer in case there was some resource hung open but this did not help anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue with this one.

Under the hood, calling `socket.settimeout(1)` or similarly calling `socket.setblocking(False)` which I also experimented with, results in the underlying socket getting set to non-blocking. The reason this becomes a problem, is that while most socket operations (for instance, just the normal `socket.recvmsg` that you call on a `sctp.sctpsocket_udp` object get delegated to the python `socket` object, the `sctp_*` calls do not, they are handled via the `_sctp.c` C extension component of pysctp. What this means, is that when you do something that causes the underlying socket to be nonblocking such as `socket.settimeout(1)`, and then use one of the `sctp_*` functions, rather than timing out and then getting a `socket.timeout` exception, you end up in this part of the underlying C extension:

```
size = sctp_recvmsg(...)
if(size < 0){
    free(msg);
    PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_IOError);
    return ret;
}
```

and thus, get the BlockingIOError referenced above. The solution is to use non-blocking mode rather than bothering with a timeout, and then to catch `BlockingIOError` instead of  `socket.timeout` and just check the `errno` attribute of the exception to make sure it was `EAGAIN` thus indicating no data available at that point, so sleep or something and then try again.

Comment: Awesome investigation.